# In my project while using the drag and drop option its not performing only if we use Robot class along, problem is Screen should be on! everytime

Tags: java, selenium, awt, awtrobot

```java
FilterColumns.sendKeys(d4);
// Thread.sleep(3000);

Robot robot1 = new Robot();
robot1.mouseMove(0, 0);

// Pass in the X and Y Coordinates of the Element (Integer)
robot1.mouseMove(AudienceOverlapTarget.getLocation().getX() + 250,
    AudienceOverlapTarget.getLocation().getY() + 180);
act.dragAndDrop(DragAudience, AudienceOverlapTarget).perform();
robot1.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
Thread.sleep(50);
robot1.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
Thread.sleep(1000);
act.release().build().perform();
Thread.sleep(5000);
//drag and drop done only with Robot class when screen is on
```

Comment: What do you mean by "[the drag and drop option is] not performing"? I'm confused by this as well: "only if we use Robot class along" --- basically I'm completely confused by your question. Can you describe what you expect to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: And be sure to update your question with this information instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: Regarding Selenium Automation :If i want to drag and drop the element from source place to destination place, it we use Actions class in selenium its not working, but if i use Robot class along with X and Y coordination then its working but while execution we should keep the screen on. So i need solution it should work with in background

Comment: What do you mean by "while execution we should keep the screen on"? Do you mean that selenium should **not** run in "headless" mode so you can see the browser window, or are you talking about testing on a mobile device where you want the screen of the phone or tablet to remain on during the test?